# Android change size of a drawable after device rotation

Tags: android, rotation, drawable

I need your help once again.

In my activity I have a TextView where I'm loading html content:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(body, p, null));
```

Since there might be some images in this content, I'm using

```
URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(textview, this);
```

to fetch them and add dynamically. The thing is that if image is smaller than width of the screen it automatically align left. So I figured to center the image I'll create wider bitmap and attach my image in a specific position, based on width of the display and the image:

```
public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) 
{
    try 
    {
        InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
        Drawable drawable;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        widthBM=bitmap.getWidth();
        heightBM=bitmap.getHeight();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;

        int w = (width - widthBM)/2+widthBM;
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, heightBM, conf);
        Canvas comboCanvas = new Canvas(b);
        comboCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (width - widthBM)/2, 0, null);

        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0+w, 0+heightBM);

        return drawable;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

And on start of the activity it works perfect - this is when starting in portrait:

[image: portrait]

and this is when starting in landscape:

[image: landscape]

The problem starts on the rotation of the device. I thought since I'm not using anything like

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in this activity and I'm not overriding onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig), the whole activity should be reloaded, onCreate should be called again and size of my drawables should be recalculated based on new screen width. But, when switching from portrait to landscape, instead of getting what's on second picture, I'm getting something like this:

[image]

When I'm checking size of the drawable it is correct (let's say 295x80px in portrait and 455x80px in landscape, where screen is 480x800px (or 800x480px when in landscape, obviously) and image 120x80px). What am I missing?

```
public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter 
{
    Context c;
    TextView container;

    public URLImageParser(TextView t, Context c) 
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.container = t;
    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) 
    {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();
        ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = new ImageGetterAsyncTask(urlDrawable);
        asyncTask.execute(source);
        return urlDrawable;
    }

    public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>  
    {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();

        public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) 
        {
            this.urlDrawable = d;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            String source = params[0];
            return fetchDrawable(source);
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) 
        { 

            urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0+(width - widthBM)/2 + widthBM, 0+heightBM);

            urlDrawable.drawable = result; 
            URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();

            URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight() + heightBM));

            URLImageParser.this.container.setEllipsize(null);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare the `widthBM` and `heightBM` (which, if I understood correctly, are the "coordinates" that tell you were to place the image) when you start with landscape to those you get when the orientation changes. If those are not equal, you may have to get the coordinates inside another event. Let me know, I did something similar once.
However, I think it would be much easier to provide different layouts for each orientation.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. WidthBM and heightBM are width and hight of a bitmap. Coordinates of top left corner of this bitmap are (width - widthBM)/2, 0 ("inside" bitmap b), they are recalculated after rotation of the device and are correct. And what do you mean by layouts? In this case, in the layout that this activity uses there's only one TextView.

Comment: Maybe you want to do it programmatically, so what I said wouldn't be suitable for you. Otherwise, you can specify a layout for portrait mode and another one for landscape: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html . So, you said those variables are the same in both cases? If it's so I will try to implement it.

Comment: Well, if I could handle this single scenario I should be fine, so displays with other resolutions, etc, aren't the issue at the moment. I have a bitmap 120x80. I'm placing it at x coordinate (480-120)/2 = 180px. After rotation the x coordinate is recalculated and equals (800-120)/2 = 340px. That's the value used in comboCanvas.drawBitmap(...), but for some reason application still uses the previous one (from portait mode, instead a landscape).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Turns out it has nothing to do with drawables. The correct answer is: don't be an idiot. And if for some reason you decide to be one, like me, don't put

```
android:freezesText="true"
```

in your textview properties.